# mapreduce file transferring implementation

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How can I implement transferring file via map-reduce?
What parameters I need to set in input-output of mapper, reducer and job in order to achieve this?

Comment: Whats wrong with `distcp`?

Comment: @mazaneicha I need my own implementation of distcp in order to understand it better

Comment: Its an open source.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming plain-text files, you would just make the mapper and reducer output exactly what they get. The output then contains all the same lines as the input.

```
void map(LongWriteable key, Text value, Context context) {
    context.write(key, value);
}
```

```
void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) {
    for (Text t : values) context.write(key, value);
}
```

Comment: And if not only text -- I need to change some interface of values for writing?

Comment: Then I would not use mapreduce and instead use Spark's `binaryFiles` method

Comment: Alternatively, I would write no code and instead setup Apache Nifi to move files around HDFS clusters

Comment: But is it possible to do with MapReduce?

Comment: Sure. You just would need to create your own input/output format and record reader/writer classes rather than use the default TextInputFormat